# Executable to try DLL hijacking attacks

Tags: windows-10, privilege-escalation

I'm doing an educational project and I need an executable to try different DLL hijacking techniques in Windows 10.

Obviously, there are no such vulnerabilities in Windows 10 by default, so I thought about creating an executable in C and compiling it just to try this kind of attack, but I am not sure how to do it cause I need it to be with elevated privileges.

The other option I was thinking about is finding some old program with this kind of known vulnerability, but I am not sure which one to use so that I can explain almost everything related to DLL hijacking.

Any ideas for any of the two proposed ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, there are no such vulnerabilities in Windows 10 by default...

Not so fast. This [list](https://www.wietzebeukema.nl/blog/hijacking-dlls-in-windows) have 287 applications shipped in Windows 10 v1909 that are vulnerable to DLL Hijacking. Just grab one of those, put a rogue DLL on its path, and run the executable. [This](https://github.com/ZemlyakovDmitry/DLL-Hijack-Calculator) is one good DLL to use. It spawns a calculator and shows a message box saying if the application got admin privileges or not.

Comment: And how or where can I download that specific version metioned on that list? Cause I hace the 20H2 19042.572 and the example shown in that article does not work

Comment: Grab a copy of Process Explorer (it should be on the Sysinternals Suite), run a program from that list and check the DLL files it tried to import but failed. Rename the DLL to match the missing file and try. It's a "relative path" issue, so you will need to start the vulnerable application from the directory you saved the DLL.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that but the proccess find the dll, so it looks like in this version those vulnerabilities have been patched